# Android Real Time Location Tracking

Tags: android, android-activity

Hello everyone I am developing two apps one for Admin and second for its employees. Now i want to track the employee device using this app the location is send to server when location of employee device changed.Location is send only when location changed. how i can send location of device to server when location is changed??
 second i want to show the location of employee on admin app map as it is changing its location.(May i send Location co ordinates from server to admin app through GCM or any other technique?)

Hey, down voters can you explain what is wrong in this question? If you have a Answer to the question the give otherwise try to understand the questions.
please help
Thanks in advance..

Comment: you can use locationlistener interface to send the changed location. For second you can use the google map api. I dont the details sorry. Just giving the headsup

Comment: how i can send location to server when location is changed??

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: how can i set distance of 50 meter on location changed method

Comment: distance of 50 mts? you mean to say locationchange notification on every 50mts?? if yes then there is a parameter described in the link i just gave

Comment: you mean i have to set if(location = 50m){ // send location to server}

Comment: yes i guess so! But please explain your problem in a good way! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public LatLng getLocation()
{
 // Get the location manager
 MyLocationListener myLocListener = new MyLocationListener();
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
 Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
 Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,timeAfteryougetUpdate, minDistanceAfterYougetupdate, myLocListener);
 Double lat,lon;
 try {
   lat = location.getLatitude ();
   lon = location.getLongitude ();
   return new LatLng(lat, lon);
 }
 catch (NullPointerException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
 }
}
```

**Use this to get location **

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
  {
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {
  if (loc != null)
  {
     // Do something knowing the location changed by the distance you requested
     methodThatDoesSomethingWithNewLocation(loc);
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0)
 {
   // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is disabled by the user
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0)
 {
    // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider is enabled by the   user
  }

  @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2)
 {
  // Do something here if you would like to know when the provider status changes
 }
 }
```

Comment: how i will set distance on location changed method??

Comment: thats just a value you have to pass in

Comment: say i have to set 25 meter when 25 meter location is changed i will send location to server through JSON now how i will set parameter to 25 meter on location changed

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,timeAfteryougetUpdate, 25, myLocListener);

Comment: one thing more when location is changed location will be sent by simple json method or i need any service for that purpose?

Comment: you have to get  lat and lng from Location and upload to your server

Comment: if u find it usefull then rate my answer

Comment: if (loc != null)
  {
     // Do something knowing the location changed by the distance you requested
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,timeAfteryougetUpdate, 25, myLocListener);                            //send lat and lang to server 
  } // that will be my code??

Comment: if (loc != null) { upload to your server }

Comment: if(loc!=null){locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,timeAfteryougetUpdate, 25, myLocListener);  upload to server} you mean to say i should do this??

Comment: there is no need to call requestLocationUpadetes here just get latLng from Location and upload them .this methos will be automatically called after the distance or time specified by u

Comment: Now can you tell me the second part of question how have to send this location from server to admin app?? May i use GCM ??

Comment: you can click on up arrow if it is useful

Comment: sure i will rate this question please tell me the second part how i will send this location from server to admin app??

Comment: u can use Gcm it allow you to send 4 kb of data at one time thats enough for the Latlng

Comment: Thanks allot that's helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

you can implement locationListener with service, you can req api from server and send data in any of form, json, xml and once you got the co-ordinates you can show them to the map.

[LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

[android-location-based-services-example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/location/android-location-based-services-example/)

Hope these can help you.

Comment: If a employee is continuously changing its location for 10 km than using continuously service will make app slow

Comment: you have to give the time and distance on which this method should call         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 35000, 10, this.locationListener);

Answer (score 0):

I know my response is a little bit late.

I will explain my answer using google maps services and firebase real-time database and Geo-Fire for easy location uploading to the cloud database.

1. Get the real-time location -

   ```
    @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // add the code to get the permission
        return;
    }
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   ```

   }

   ```
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   ```

   }

   ```
    @Override public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
   ```

   }

   ```
    @Override     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if(getApplicationContext() != null) {
        mlasLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); // plot the realtime location on the map
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));      
        addToDataBase(latLng);
    }
   ```

   }
2. Adding the real-time location to the cloud database using Geo-Fire

   ```
   public void addtoDataBase(LatLng location){
    //unique name work like a promary key
    String uid = "119-userID";
    final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("SOSRequests");
    GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(databaseReference);
    geoFire.setLocation(uid, new GeoLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude));
   ```

   }